# How to solve error :Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-turtlebot3_bringup

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please help me
After I run the command

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot3_bringup
```

it show this error

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-turtlebot3_bringup
```

is there any related with the case compile the turtlebot3_bringup package

help me please,tq

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354540/how-to-solve-error-:unable-to-locate-package-ros-kinetic-turtlebot3_bringup/) by [irsyad](https://answers.ros.org/users/55370/irsyad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot3_bringup
> ```

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot3-bringup
```

Note the `-` instead of the `_`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [irsyad](https://answers.ros.org/users/55370/irsyad/) on 2020-06-11**:
it show the same error

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-12**:
Then please show us the output of:

```
uname -rvmp
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
lsb_release -a
```